# How to stop the propagation of waves?

Tags: waves, inertia

I am trying to understand Newtonian equivalent law of inertia for the waves.
Roughly Newton's law of inertia says that an object which is in motion in space will continue to remain in motion unless an external force is applied.
If I apply enough force I can stop the object from moving.

I want to apply that to waves.
Imagine that a wave is propagating on the surface of the water.

My question is under what conditions the propagating wave can be stopped? What should I apply to bring the wave to rest ?

Comment: Unclear.  Do you want to "freeze the ocean" and stop wave motion but leave the wave peaks and troughs standing still, or rather cause the water to become smooth?  And are you asking how to do this to a large body of water, or, somewhat more simply, cause the motion to be stopped past some barricade or mechanism which performs the transformation?

Comment: I want to stop the further propagation of wave anyhow. I am asking this for a large body of water in which a wave has been generated at some point on the surface of water.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to reflect the wave - for that you would just need to build a wall - you have to somehow absorb the wave energy by converting it to some other form of energy.

This, at least to some extent, can be achieved with various devices designed to capture wind wave energy. Many of them are described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_power).

One of the ideas here is that such devices have to resist the wave in just the right way. If the resistance is too high (an immovable wall) or too low (a toy water wheel), not much energy transfer will occur. We can say that in order to maximize energy transfer a good impedance matching is required.

If a number of rows of such devices will be placed along the wave front, each row absorbing a fraction of the wave energy, we could expect that eventually the wave will be weakened enough and we could declare that it has been effectively stopped.